# Viewstate and controls in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, viewstate

I posted a question a couple of days ago about viewstate and after running some tests I have come to some conclusions/results. Based on these results I have a few questions as to how someone would do certain things.

Here are the results of my tests that I ran:

1. If usercontrolA is loaded from `OnInit` of a Page, then his viewstate will be available in `OnLoad`. All other controls that usercontrolA loads from it's `OnInit`, will have their viewstate ready in their `OnLoad`.
2. If usercontrolA is loaded from `OnLoad` of a Page, then his viewstate will be available in `OnPreRender`. All other controls that usercontrolA loads from it's `OnLoad`, will have their viewstate available in their `OnPreRender`.
3. If usercontrolA is loaded from an event (Example: button click. Events fire after `OnLoad` and before `OnPreRender`) of a Page, then his viewstate will not be available. All other controls that usercontrolA loades will not have their viewstate available.

So in a perfect world you would always load all controls using situation #1, so that their viewstate is available on their `OnLoad`. Unfortunately when you need to load a control from a button click or from a `OnLoad`, is there no way for control to get its viewstate before `OnPreRender` stage?

I have read a bunch of articles on viewstate and thought I understood it, but working on my current application which loads usercontrols which load other usercontrols, I am having a real hard time with being able to get viewstate on my leaf (last in the chain) usercontrol.

Any suggestions and/or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is accepted practice to load dynamic controls in OnInit, so that they get the full control lifecycle. I'm not sure I particularly understand your situation though - if you're loading a control based on a button click, why would it have viewstate at that point? On the *next* OnInit, you should load the control *again* (I usually use a page level Viewstate item to track that a particular control needs to be loaded) so that it can *restore* from Viewstate. Something like:

```
class Default : Page {
   enum LoadedControl { Textbox, Label, GridView }

   override OnInit() {
      if (IsPostback) {
        var c = Viewstate["LoadedControl"] as LoadedControl;
        if (c != null) LoadDynamicControl(c);
      }
   }

   void Button_Click() {
     var c = (LoadedControl)Enum.Parse(typeof(LoadedControl), ddl.SelectedValue);
     LoadDynamicControl(c);
   }

   void LoadDynamicControl(LoadedControl c) {
     switch (c) {
        case LoadedControl.Textbox:
           this.ph.Controls.Add(new Textbox());
           break;
        ...
     }

     ViewState["LoadedControl"] = c;
   }
}
```

The slightly more interesting bit, though, is that according to catch-up events - it really shouldn't matter. The callstack for dynamically loading a control looks something like:

```
Control.Controls.Add(Control)
   Control.AddedControl(Control)
      Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(object)
          Control.LoadViewState(object)
```

Taking `Label` as an example, it overrides `LoadViewState` and pulls it's `Text` property directly from ViewState. TextBox is similar. So, by my reading, it should be OK to add at any point, and then access ViewState. That doesn't seem to be jive with my experience, though, so further investigation seems warranted.

Comment: Hi, This was one of my issues why I was trying to use viewstate. I needed to mark somehow that my control needs to be loaded on the next postback after it was loaded by a onclick handler on the previous postback. I was thinking about using the viewstate from the page which will have the values. In my tests it seems this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think I can add anything that this article doesn't cover.

Look specifically at the **Life Cycle Events** section.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised but interested about your results. When I work with dynamic controls I always add them in `Page_Init`. Anything else doesn't work. But you are right - how do you do it if you are adding them in response to a button click.

The only way I have found is by examining `Request.Form("__EVENTTARGET")` collection at `PageInit`. This contains the control ID of the control that has triggered the postback so for instance a button click. It will of course be qualified by the naming containers it appears in. Once you have identified the 'event' by this method you can add the controls you want.

It is of course all a bit hacky but it's the only way I found of doing these things. It does work.

It's interesting that the `ViewState` is available on `PreRender` if you add the controls at `Page_Load`. But as the above link indicates it too late to help you then. The controls state is rehydrated during the load cycle. If it's not there then your control state or dynamic controls are just going to disappear.

Comment: I think he's failing to differentiate between Viewstate being available and being persisted between postbacks.  Viewstate is loaded from previous postbacks during Page.Load, which means if you create the control during a Page.Load handler, it will miss having its viewstate automatically persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `LoadComplete` event?

Use this event for tasks that require that all other controls on the page be loaded.

This is fired *after* `PageLoad` and all events (ButtonClick, etc.), so your UserControls are are loaded in ButtonClick events, and in `LoadComplete` their ViewState is already initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am not sure I am following. One of the usercontrols needs to get a value from its viewstate. LoadComplete is on the Page level.

Comment: if you want an event where you know what click events have occurred, LoadComplete is the first.